# How can I get the title of a page on another site?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Pretty long question;

How can I do the following in C#:

Open a web page (Preferably not visible)
Check whether the page redirects to a different page (Site is down, 404, etc.)
Check if the title is not equal to a said string

Then separately, (They need to click a confirm button)

open their browser, and go to the address of the first (It'll be the only one) hyperlink on the site.

I literally have been looking on Google for ages and haven't found anything similar to what I need.

Whether you give me a link to a site with a tutorial on this area of programming or actual source code doesn't make a difference to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use WebRequest or HttpWebRequest, but if you want a browser UI you will need to use the WebBrowser control: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx

You will need to handle the completion event from the Navigate call which will load the page for you:

```
WebBrowser myWebBrowser = new WebBrowser();

webBrowser1.Navigating += new WebBrowserNavigatingEventHandler(webBrowser1_IDontKnow);
myWebBrowser.Navigate("http://myurl.com/mypage.htm");
```

You can then implement your handler as follows, and interact with the WebBrowser ui as necessary... the DocumentText property contains the HTML of the currently loaded web page:

```
private void webBrowser1_IDontKnow(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)

   {

      CheckHTMLConfirmAndRedirect(webBrowser1.DocumentText);

    }
```

Comment: Seems easier and more efficient. I can make it invisible and do the tests, and error or make it visible, allowing them to click hyperlink. Honestly don't know which answer to pick, they all have advantages.

Comment: Glad you decided to pick my suggestion!  Best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

check out the [webrequest class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx), it can do redirection :) then you can just parse the html and find the title tag using xpath or something

sort of like this

```
  using System.Xml;
  using System.Xml.XPath;
  using System.Xml.Linq;
  using System.Net;

  ...

  HttpWebRequest myReq = ( HttpWebRequest )WebRequest.Create( "http://www.contoso.com/" );
  myReq.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
  myReq.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 5;
  XNode result;
  using( var responseStream = myReq.GetResponse( ).GetResponseStream( ) ) {
    result = XElement.Load( responseStream );
  }

  var title = result.XPathSelectElement( "//title" ).Value;
```

obviosly your xpath can (and probably should) be more sophisticated :) you can find out more on xpath [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp)

on a similar note you can use xpath on the xml you get back to find the links and pick out the first one:

```
  var links = result.XPathSelectElements( "//a" ).Select( linktag => linktag.Attribute( "href" ).Value );
```

when you eventually find the url you want to open you can use

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start( links.First() );
```

to get it to open in the browser. a nice aspect of this is that it will open what ever browser is the default for the client. it does have security implications though, you should make sure that its an url and not an exe file or something.

also, its possible that the html use diffrent capital letters for its elements, you'd have to deal with that when looking for linsk

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that. Can you send across $_POST[] PHP variables? If so then I can just make PHP do all the work :)

Comment: i dont know very much about php im afraid, but you can send url parameters and headers if you like. the webrequest class doesnt do any kind of parsing or processing of the result though, it will only give you a raw byte stream that you can pipe into things like XmlReader

Answer (score 1):

Use HttpWebRequest and parse the response:

```
private static void method1()
{
    string strWORD = "pain";
    const string WORDWEBURI = "http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=";

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(WORDWEBURI + strWORD.ToUpper());
    request.UserAgent = @"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0)";
    request.ContentType = "text/html";

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    string tempString = null;
    int count = 0;

    do
    {
        // fill the buffer with data
        count = resStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        // make sure we read some data
        if (count != 0)
        {
            // translate from bytes to ASCII text
            tempString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, count);

            // continue building the string
            sb.Append(tempString);
        }
    }

    while (count > 0); // any more data to read?

    Console.Write(sb.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Oh god that's much more than I would've expected. Thanks though

Comment: How is this different from using WebClient.DownloadString()? Besides being able to set user agent and whatnot. What benefit does reading a stream give?

Comment: webservers might redirecting automated aotomated requests. setting useragent is part of the effort to get a response.